# International domains - best practices

Tags: domains

I need to create a Russian website with a .ru domain extension. How would I go about this? What are some best practices for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

From "need", I'm inferring this is somehow oriented towards commercial activity. As such:

Best practice: avoid doing business in former Soviet Union in the first place (see "Dealing with the Devil, First rule, of").

If you can't avoid that, at least, if you can, register through some big name company headquartered outside of fUSSR, and definitely host outside fUSSR.

Reasons are many and varied, including the levels of corruption (not only graft is an **expected** cost of doing business at pretty much all levels, but the bureaucrats aren't even honest in the sense of having been bought, stay bought); and the level of control over any media, Internet included, by FSB.

On the technical side, as already mentioned, there's no difference between this and .com, other than the set of registrars that are selling .ru domains.

On the legal side, there may be issues from Russia's side on legality of non-russian entity owning `.ru` domain but i never heard of such. As usual, consult with a real lawyer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Goodness me, you are a narrow-minded xenophobic sterotype-reinforcing unhelpful soul.

Comment: Has no-one informed you squire? The cold-war is over.

Comment: @Tom, @pobk - I grew up there. AND actually know in detail what's happening there now. That makes me a LOT more of an expert than either of you. Get off your idiotic high horse and take back your politically motivated ill-informed downvotes, please.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking here - but it probably belongs on serverfault.

To register a .RU domain, try [NIC](http://www.nic.ru/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Alan right, it's a ServerFault quiestion, but in any way creating that site is not more complex then creating .com web-site :) You may buy russian hosting with auto .ru registration (net.ru for example) or register domain yourself with your favorite registrator